# Simple prettyprint program not working

Tags: javascript, css, pretty-print

I am trying to use prettyprint to format the UI of my code but I am not getting any formatting done.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/r298/prettify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="prettyPrint()">   
<pre class="prettyprint">   
  &lt;div&gt; This is a div &lt;/div&gt;   
  &lt;a href="http://www.google.com"&gt;Bollywood &lt;/a &gt;   
</pre>  
</body>
</html>
```

References:

> 1. https://github.com/google/code-prettify
> 2. https://github.com/google/code-prettify/blob/master/docs/getting_started.md
> 3. https://rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/styles/index.html

Can someone please help me out?

> ```
> I want the default layout in the 3rd link provided.
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/r298/prettify.min.css">
  <style type="text/css"></style><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/prettify.css">
</head>
<body>

  <pre class="prettyprint linenums">
    &lt;div&gt; This is a div &lt;/div&gt;   
    &lt;a href="http://www.google.com"&gt;Bollywood &lt;/a &gt;   
  </pre>

</body>
</html>
```

An online demo is available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gnbyaamL/).

The desired theme must be included as a css file (for example, [this css file](https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/styles/sunburst.css)).

Answer (score 2):

Your link to code is invalid.

https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js
Use this one:

```
https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js
```